# Having clause along with 'case when' in CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I want to build the having clause shown below using `CriteriaBuilder` :

```sql
select objectid,
   sum(case when attr_meta = 'severity' then 1 else 0 end) as severity,
   sum(case when attr_meta = 'priority' then 1 else 0 end) as priority
from object d
group by objectid
having sum(case when attr_meta = 'severity' then 1 else 0 end) != 1 
    or sum(case when attr_meta = 'priority' then 1 else 0 end) != 1;
```

I tried the below approach:

```
Predicate p = cb.equal(cb.sum(cb.<Integer>selectCase()
    .when(cb.equal(root.get("name"), 'severity'), 1).otherwise(0)), 1);
p = cb.or(p, cb.equal(cb.sum(cb.<Integer>selectCase()
    .when(cb.equal(root.get("name"), 'priority'), 1).otherwise(0)), 1));
```

but this gives the below exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.ValueHandlerFactory.isNumeric(ValueHandlerFactory.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.predicate.ComparisonPredicate.<init>(ComparisonPredicate.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaBuilderImpl.equal(CriteriaBuilderImpl.java:392)
```

The exception seems to be coming from the outer `CriteriaBuilderImpl.equal()` call, the one that encloses `selectCase()` call.

The `equal()` call internally needs type info of the `Expression`. The `selectCase()` call, while creating the `Expression`, puts in type as `null`. Do we have some way to handle this situation? Either a way to let the `equal()` know the type, or a completely different approach to the above mentioned query?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Just replace all literals with `CriteriaBuilder#literal(T value)` such as `cb.literal(0)`, `cb.literal(1)` etc : http://stackoverflow.com/a/34302569/1391249

Answer (score 8):

Performing typecast upon expression (by using [Expression#as(Class)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Expression.html#as%28java.lang.Class%29)) could help.

```
Expression<Integer> sumExp = builder.sum(
            builder.<Integer>selectCase()
            .when(builder.equal(root.get("name"), "severity"), 1)
            .otherwise(0)
    );
Predicate eqPredicate = builder.equal(sumExp.as(Integer.class), 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the answer to this is to have a cb.nullLiteral return for as the ".otherwise" part of the clause. This is the solution that got all this working for me. See example below. If this helps, please flag this answer.

```
cb.count(cb.selectCase().when( status.get("maxAction").in( introTypes ), 1).otherwise(cb.nullLiteral(Number.class)) ),
```