# Using the 'case...when...then...else...end' construct in the 'having' clause in JPA criteria query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria, criteria-api, having

The following criteria query calculates the average of rating of different groups of products.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple>criteriaQuery=criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Tuple.class);
Metamodel metamodel=entityManager.getMetamodel();
EntityType<Product>entityType=metamodel.entity(Product.class);
Root<Product>root=criteriaQuery.from(entityType);
SetJoin<Product, Rating> join = root.join(Product_.ratingSet, JoinType.LEFT);

Expression<Number> quotExpression = criteriaBuilder.quot(criteriaBuilder.sum(join.get(Rating_.ratingNum)), criteriaBuilder.count(join.get(Rating_.ratingNum)));
Expression<Integer> roundExpression = criteriaBuilder.function("round", Integer.class, quotExpression);
Expression<Object> selectExpression = criteriaBuilder.selectCase().when(quotExpression.isNull(), 0).otherwise(roundExpression );

criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.tuple(root.get(Product_.prodId).alias("prodId"), selectExpression.alias("rating")));
criteriaQuery.groupBy(root.get(Product_.prodId));

criteriaQuery.having(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(roundExpression, 0));
criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(Product_.prodId)));

TypedQuery<Tuple> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Tuple> tuples = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

It generates the following SQL query :

```sql
SELECT product0_.prod_id AS col_0_0_, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Sum(ratingset1_.rating_num) / Count(ratingset1_.rating_num) IS 
              NULL THEN 
         0 
         ELSE Round(Sum(ratingset1_.rating_num) / Count(ratingset1_.rating_num)) 
       END AS col_1_0_ 
FROM   social_networking.product product0_ 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN social_networking.rating ratingset1_ 
                    ON product0_.prod_id = ratingset1_.prod_id 
GROUP  BY product0_.prod_id 
HAVING Round(Sum(ratingset1_.rating_num) / Count(ratingset1_.rating_num)) >= 0 
ORDER  BY product0_.prod_id DESC
```

The `case...when` structure replaces `null` values with `0`, if the specified expression in the `case` clause is evaluated to `null`.

I need the same `case...when` construct in the `having` clause so that the group of rows returned by the `group by` clause can be filtered by replacing `null` with `0` in the list of values calculated by the `case...when` construct, if any.

Accordingly, the `having` clause should be generated like

```sql
HAVING
    (CASE
        WHEN Sum(ratingset1_.rating_num)/Count(ratingset1_.rating_num) IS
             NULL THEN 0 
        ELSE Round(sum(ratingset1_.rating_num)/Count(ratingset1_.rating_num))
    END)>=0
```

It could be possible, if in the `greaterThanOrEqualTo()` method, `selectExpression` instead of `roundExpression` is given but it is not possible. Doing so, generates a compile-time error indicating type mismatch between `Expression<Integer>` and `Expression<Object>`.

So how can I have the same `case...when` structure  in the `having` clause as in the `select` clause?

<sub>I have also tried by removing the generic type parameter `Object` of the expression like `Expression selectExpression` but doing so, caused the `NullPointerException` to be thrown.</sub>

---

Moreover, alias names (`prodId`, `rating`) as given in the `select` clause have no effect in the generated SQL as can be seen. Why columns are not aliased here? Am I missing something?

If columns are aliased then, it should be possible to write the `having` clause just like follows.

```
having rating>=0
```

and `having` in the criteria query should be as follows,

```
criteriaQuery.having(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(join.<Integer>get("rating"), 0));
```

but as columns are not aliased in the `select` clause, it throws an exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve attribute [rating] against path [null]
```

---

What is the way to get around this situation? Anyway, the rows returned by `Group by` should be filtered by replacing `null` with `0` in the list of values produced by `case...when` in the `select` clause.

---

I'm using JPA 2.0 provided by Hibernate 4.2.7 final.

---

**EDIT:**

I have tried with the following expression :

```
Expression<Integer> selectExpression = criteriaBuilder.<Integer>selectCase()
                                       .when(quotExpression.isNull(), 0)
                                       .<Integer>otherwise(roundExpression);
```

but it caused the following exception to be thrown :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.ValueHandlerFactory.isNumeric(ValueHandlerFactory.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.predicate.ComparisonPredicate.<init>(ComparisonPredicate.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaBuilderImpl.greaterThanOrEqualTo(CriteriaBuilderImpl.java:468)
```

How can the following expression work then,

```
Expression<Integer> roundExpression = criteriaBuilder
                              .function("round", Integer.class, quotExpression);
```

both have the same type?

Is there a way to put the `case...when` structure in the `having` clause?

---

**EDIT**

Changing the expression type to

```
Expression<Integer> selectExpression = criteriaBuilder
                                       .<Integer>selectCase()
                                       .when(quotExpression.isNull(), 0)
                                       .<Integer>otherwise(roundExpression);
```

in **EclipseLink (2.3.2)** works hence, it can be made available in the `having` clause.

In case of Hibernate provider, it throws the `NullPoiterExcpetion`, if an attempt is made to change the expression type of `selectCase()` (which returns `Expression<Object>` by default).

---

**Update :**

This issue still persists in Hibernate 5.0.5 final.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very unlikely to be a bug in Hibernate. There was a technical mistake in fabricating the criteria query given. Taking the same example but in a simpler form.

Let's assume that we are interested in generating the following SQL query.

```sql
SELECT
    p.prod_id,
    p.prod_name,
    CASE
        WHEN sum(r.rating_num)/count(DISTINCT r.rating_id) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE round(sum(r.rating_num)/count(DISTINCT r.rating_id))
    END AS avg_rating
FROM
    product p
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    rating r
        ON p.prod_id=r.prod_id
GROUP BY
    p.prod_id,
    p.prod_name 
HAVING
    CASE
        WHEN sum(r.rating_num)/count(DISTINCT r.rating_id) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE round(sum(r.rating_num)/count(DISTINCT r.rating_id))
    END>=1
```

Based on the following table in MySQL.

```
mysql> desc rating;
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| rating_id   | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| prod_id     | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| rating_num  | int(10) unsigned    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ip_address  | varchar(45)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| row_version | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

This table `rating` has an obvious many-to-one relationship with another table `product` (`prod_id` is the foreign key referencing the primary key `prod_id` in the `product` table).

In this question, we are only interested in the `CASE` construct in the `HAVING` clause.

The following criteria query,

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();
Root<Product> root = criteriaQuery.from(entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(Product.class));
ListJoin<Product, Rating> prodRatingJoin = root.join(Product_.ratingList, JoinType.LEFT);

List<Expression<?>> expressions = new ArrayList<Expression<?>>();
expressions.add(root.get(Product_.prodId));
expressions.add(root.get(Product_.prodName));

Expression<Integer> sum = criteriaBuilder.sum(prodRatingJoin.get(Rating_.ratingNum));
Expression<Long> count = criteriaBuilder.countDistinct(prodRatingJoin.get(Rating_.ratingId));

Expression<Number> quotExpression = criteriaBuilder.quot(sum, count);
Expression<Integer> roundExpression = criteriaBuilder.function("round", Integer.class, quotExpression);
Expression<Integer> selectExpression = criteriaBuilder.<Integer>selectCase().when(quotExpression.isNull(), criteriaBuilder.literal(0)).otherwise(roundExpression);
expressions.add(selectExpression);

criteriaQuery.multiselect(expressions.toArray(new Expression[0]));
expressions.remove(expressions.size() - 1);

criteriaQuery.groupBy(expressions.toArray(new Expression[0]));
criteriaQuery.having(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(selectExpression, criteriaBuilder.literal(1)));

List<Tuple> list = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();

for (Tuple tuple : list) {
    System.out.println(tuple.get(0) + " : " + tuple.get(1) + " : " + tuple.get(2));
}
```

Generates the following correct SQL query as expected.

```sql
select
    product0_.prod_id as col_0_0_,
    product0_.prod_name as col_1_0_,
    case 
        when sum(ratinglist1_.rating_num)/count(distinct ratinglist1_.rating_id) is null then 0 
        else round(sum(ratinglist1_.rating_num)/count(distinct ratinglist1_.rating_id)) 
    end as col_2_0_ 
from
    projectdb.product product0_ 
left outer join
    projectdb.rating ratinglist1_ 
        on product0_.prod_id=ratinglist1_.prod_id 
group by
    product0_.prod_id ,
    product0_.prod_name 
having
    case 
        when sum(ratinglist1_.rating_num)/count(distinct ratinglist1_.rating_id) is null then 0 
        else round(sum(ratinglist1_.rating_num)/count(distinct ratinglist1_.rating_id)) 
    end>=1
```

For the technical perspective, look at the following line in the above criteria query.

```
criteriaQuery.having(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(selectExpression, criteriaBuilder.literal(1)));
```

Its analogous line in the question was written like following.

```
createQuery.having(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(selectExpression, 1));
```

See the original expression in the question doing the exact same thing :

```
Expression<Integer> selectExpression = criteriaBuilder.<Integer>selectCase()
                                       .when(quotExpression.isNull(), 0)
                                       .<Integer>otherwise(roundExpression);
```

This expression was attempted to be passed to `criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo()` as follows.

```
criteriaQuery.having(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(selectExpression, 0));
```

Pay special attention to the second parameter to `greaterThanOrEqualTo()` above. It is `0`. It should have been `criteriaBuilder.literal(0)` instead hence, the exception as mentioned in the question.

Thus, always insist upon using `CriteriaBuilder#literal(T value)` for literal values whenever necessary as done above while using expressions in the `CriteriaBuilder#selectCase()` construct.

---

<sub>Tested on Hibernate 4.3.6 final, Hibernate 5.0.5 final alternatively. <s>I will try to run the same query on EclipseLink (2.6.1 final) later on. There should not be a quirk anymore.</s></sub>

<sub>EclipseLink has no problem at all with the modified version of the query except that it requires an `Object` type parameter to the constructor argument (formal parameter), if constructor expressions are used in place of `Tuple` which this question has nothing to do with after all. This is a long-standing bug in EclipseLink still to be fixed - [an analogous example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23217062/1391249).</sub>

Comment: @Tinay CriteriaBuilder 's quot() method returns only quotient. How to get fractional part also?